# Endless horizontal jQuery ticker

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for an endless horizontal news style ticker. I've played around with SmoothScroll and SimpleDivScroll.

SmoothScroll doesn't seem to work well with elements of different widths and SimpleDivScroll is only compatible with jQuery 1.4+ and I'm stuck with jQuery 1.3.2.

Any other alternatives?

Comment: When you say endless, do you want it to keep pulling in new data to display? Or do you want it to display a previously defined finite amount of data that wraps around so that it can keep scrolling from right to left?

Comment: Previously defined finite amount of data that wraps around again.

Comment: See https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/ticker/ for an overview on all available ticker plugins for jQuery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

[jQuery Twitter Marquee by Takien](http://web.archive.org/web/20150418135301/http://cektkp.com:80/twittermarquee/)

Comment: Unfortunately, this link is now broken.

Comment: I've fixed this link to the creator's website, but unfortunately all the code examples have gone.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple ticker. I haven't tested it in all browsers.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Horizontal scroller</title>
<style type="text/css">
#scroller{height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;line-height:30px;position:relative;}
#scroller li{float:left;height:30px;padding:0 0 0 10px;list-style-position:inside;}
#scrollerWrapper{height:30px;margin:30px;overflow:hidden;border:1px #333 solid;background:#F2F2F2;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var speed = 5;
    var items, scroller = $('#scroller');
    var width = 0;
    scroller.children().each(function(){
        width += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    });
    scroller.css('width', width);
    scroll();
    function scroll(){
        items = scroller.children();
        var scrollWidth = items.eq(0).outerWidth();
        scroller.animate({'left' : 0 - scrollWidth}, scrollWidth * 100 / speed, 'linear', changeFirst);
    }
    function changeFirst(){
        scroller.append(items.eq(0).remove()).css('left', 0);
        scroll();
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="scrollerWrapper">
<ul id="scroller">
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
<li> Maecenas sollicitudin, ante id ultrices consectetur, ipsum nisl varius ipsum, sit amet congue eros nulla vitae urna.</li>
<li>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. </li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try the [jQuery webTicker](http://jonmifsud.com/web-tools/jquery-webticker/) it is the only one to not stop the scrolling after the whole list completes. As it continously rotates your items. You can use multiple ones per page and style each one indipendently. A CSS sample is also provided on the page itself

It has not been tested with jQuery 1.3 however its fully compatible with jQuery 1.4,1.5 and 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [liScroll](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html)? Depending on what you mean by "endless", it might do what you need (there is a gap between the last item and the wraparound).

Answer (score 0):

There is the [jQuery.Marquee](https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee) plugin. License: ISC.

Other available plugins are listed at https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/ticker/.